# Bash associative array with list as value

Tags: arrays, bash, dictionary, associative-array

I have to work with an output of a Java tool, which returns a map data structure that looks like `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>`. I have to work with BASH and i tried to declare it as an associative array, what is very similar to a map. The declaration of the associative array in bash should be in one line, i try to do this as following.

```
ARRAY=(["sem1"]=("first name" "second name") ["sem2"]=("third name") ["sem3]=OTHER_LITS)
```

But this creates the following error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I can define this line by line, but i want to have it in one line. How can i define a assoviative array in bash in only one line?

Comment: No map/dictionary functionality in bash????

Comment: No there are no multi-dimensional arrays in BASH

Comment: Any suggestion how to solve my problem?

Comment: You haven't explained the problem. Why do you need multi-dimensional arrays? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm getting an output of an Java tool, which is a Map datastructure.. and i have to work with this map in the bash environment.

Comment: Can you figure it out in an answer please?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

BTW, associative array, dictionary or map - all come into the one abstract data type (let's call it a *dictionary*).

So, here is the solution for storing *array* as values in the *dictionary* of Bash (4+ version).

Note, that *array* in Bash is a space delimited list of strings (so no any spaces inside the element, i.e. string), so we could write a quoted list:

`"firstname middlename secondname"`

as a value of the `s1` key in our `X` dictionary:

```sh
declare -A X=(
  ['s1']="firstname middlename secondname"
  ['s2']="surname nickname"
  ['s3']="other"
)
```

Now we can get the value of the `s1` key as array:

`declare -a names=(${X[s1]})`

Variable `names` now contains *array*:

```
> echo $names
firstname

> echo ${names[1]}
middlename

> echo ${#names[@]}
3
```

Finally, your question part where the strings with spaces were shown:

`"first name"`, `"second name"`

Let's do a trick - represent a *space* as a special symbol sequence (it could be just one symbol), for example, double underscores:

`"first__name"`, `"second__name"`

Declare our *dictionary* again, but with "escaped" spaces inside array elements:

```sh
declare -A X=(
  ['s1']="first__name middle__name second__name"
  ['s2']="surname nickname"
  ['s3']="other"
)
```

In this case after we get the value of the `s1` key as array:

`declare -a names=(${X[s1]})`

We need to post process our array elements to remove `__` the space-replacements to the actual *space* symbols. To do this we simply use replace commands of Bash strings:

```
> echo ${names/__/ }
first name

> echo ${names[1]/__/ }
middle name

> echo ${#names[@]}
3
```

Comment: This is a brilliant solution.

Comment: This has not worked for me with bash `5.0.17(1)-release`. `echo $names` prints "firstname middlename secondname".

Answer (score 5):

In the absence of multi-dimensional array support in BASH, you can use this **word-around** associative array. Each `key` in the associative array is string concatenation of `map-index,array-list-index`:

```
# use one line declaration
declare -A array=([sem1,0]="first name" [sem1,1]="second name" [sem2,0]="third name" [sem3,0]="foo bar")

# loop thrpugh the map array
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do echo "$i => ${array[$i]}"; done
sem2,0 => third name
sem1,0 => first name
sem1,1 => second name
sem3,0 => foo bar
```

Comment: Hehe, this is clever.

Answer (score 1):

A more ergonomic solution that doesn't force the manipulation of the keys.

```
# your data with spaces
array=(1 '2 with space' 3 "4 with space and ' symbol")
declare -p array

# quote it with " and store it, your data can't contain double quote
declare -A associative=([x]=x [array]=$(printf '"%s" ' "${array[@]}"))
declare -p associative

# get your data in another array
eval deserialized_array=(${associative[array]})
declare -p deserialized_array

echo ${deserialized_array[3]}

# or let bash handle everything

# note: array contain data with double quote character
array=(1 '2 with space' 3 "4 with space and ' \" symbol")

declare -A associative=([x]=x [array]=$(declare -p array))
declare -p associative

array=() # make sure data is gone

# get the data in the same array 
eval ${associative[array]}
echo ${array[3]}
```

Comment: Nice tricks. But without explanations aimed at actually educating the reader, this isn't that helpful.

Comment: @huyz, which part of the OT question and the comments explaining what the code is doing do you need to be explain more?

Comment: I wrote that question _before_ you edited your answer and added comments. The answer is fine now